# A1 notation V4. Can not access sheet with specified name

Tags: google-sheets-api

What is the right way to create range request for a sheet with name like `'][_('`

I get error:

```
curl 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1fAdl80klrzQtPVu-ZJE4qcYhlPippj96xaQFpr3OE2k/values/"%5D%5B(_"!1:1?majorDimension=ROWS&valueRenderOption=UNFORMATTED_VALUE' -H 'Authorization: Bearer mytoken'

{
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Unable to parse range: \"][(_\"!1:1",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/values/'%5D%5B_('!1:1`

or

`GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/values/%5D%5B_(!1:1`

Basically what you had above, except using single quotes or no quotes.  Double-quotes aren't a supported way to surround the sheet name.

You can find out for yourself in the future by using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.values.get) and plugging in the values you'd like -- it will spit out the proper URL-encoded GET request.